# Issue with Guava MapDifference is not returning the diffrence but both maps

Tags: hashmap, guava

```
    public static Map<String, MapDifference.ValueDifference<String>> mapCompare(HashMap<String, String> hm, HashMap<String,String> hm2){
    MapDifference<String, String> diff = Maps.difference(hm, hm2);

    Map<String, MapDifference.ValueDifference<String>> entriesDiffering = diff.entriesDiffering();

    System.out.println("difrence  is -->" +entriesDiffering);
    return entriesDiffering;
}
```

## hm1(hashmap1 value)

> 1:abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfasd

## hm2

> 1:abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfas**2**d

**Notice the hm2 4th key entry has a different value.

### Actual OutPut

diffrence is -->{**1=(abc** 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfasd, **abc** 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfas2d)}

Note:- the First key is separated with = in first map, while second map first key is missing altogether) not sure reason. but this is not what i am trying to resolve.

### Expected: (Only the difference)

4:[]asdfas***2***d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if inputs are proper maps with 4 entries, as shown here (I use [`Splitter#withKeyValueSeparator`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#withKeyValueSeparator(java.lang.String)) to parse string to map:

```
@Test
public void properlyParsedMaps() {
    Map<String, String> map1 = MAP_SPLITTER.split("1:abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfasd");  // {1=abc, 2=xyz, 3=eedd, 4=[]asdfasd}
    Map<String, String> map2 = MAP_SPLITTER.split("1:abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfas2d"); // {1=abc, 2=xyz, 3=eedd, 4=[]asdfas2d}
    mapCompare(map1, map2); // signature slightly changed to accept any `Map`, not just `HashMap`
    // difrence  is -->{4=([]asdfasd, []asdfas2d)}
}
```

On the other hand in your example it seems you have maps with one key `"1"` and value which is the rest of the string (so probably not parsed as you expected):

```
@Test
public void reverseEngineeredMapsFromOutput() {
    Map<String, String> map1 = ImmutableMap.of("1", "abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfasd");  // {1=abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfasd}
    Map<String, String> map2 = ImmutableMap.of("1", "abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfas2d"); // {1=abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfas2d}
    mapCompare(map1, map2);
    // difrence  is -->{1=(abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfasd, abc 2:xyz 3:eedd 4:[]asdfas2d)}
}
```

Please make sure you input arguments contain what you expect.

Comment: Thanks!! you are an Angel. I used Splitter.MapSplitter to fix map issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902853/how-to-convert-a-map-to-fileline-with-certain-keys-highlighted-in-red